# When I use append operation on my array all elements become to have the same value

Tags: arrays, swift, append

I have class Order:

```
class Order {
var type_id = ""
var model_id = ""
var hourly = serviceByHours()
var transfer = serviceByTransfer()
var custom = serviceByReis()
}

struct serviceByHours {
    var undefinedTime = "1"
    var addressOfRequest = ""
    var addressOfDelivery = ""
    var detailedText = ""
    var startofWork = ""
   var endOfWork = ""
}

struct serviceByTransfer {

   var addressOfRequest = ""
   var addressOfDelivery = ""
   var detailedText = ""
   var startofWork = ""
}

struct serviceByReis {

   var addressOfRequest = ""
   var addressOfDelivery = ""
   var detailedText = ""
   var startofWork = ""
   var priceProposed = ""
}
```

I create instance of this class and fill it with values.
 after I create `Array: var singleOrderClass = Order();`
`var arrayOfOrders = [Order]` with the type of order. 
However When I use append operation`(arrayOfOrders.append(singleOrderClass))`

all my elements become to have the same value. I don't know why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am responding with an answer because I want to show a screen capture of my output for your problem. I cannot replicate what you are seeing. Is there something more to this problem?

[image]

After your (OP's) comments, I have extended the response with the following capture. Everything is working as it should. Since the array is a collection of **references** and not copies of your data, you are most likely overwriting your instance values somehow. Be sure that you instantiate a new Order() class for every element you append to the array. Do not simply reuse singleOrderClass between appends without creating a new Order() object first.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are on right way. After filling singleClass I append it to arrayOfOrders:  arrayOfOrders.append(singleOrderClass)
        for singleArr in arrayOfOrders{
            println("start of work hourly \(singleArr.hourly.startofWork)")
            println("transfer address of request \(singleArr.transfer.addressOfRequest)")
            println("reis price proposed \(singleArr.custom.priceProposed)")
            println("size of array \(arrayOfOrders.count)")
        }
    }

Comment: when I add second element to array the first element and second element become the same

Comment: they have the same value. I dont know why I am losing the values of first element